# Opacity with Reveal Modal and IE10

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I am having a rather odd problem with a client website.  I implemented a simple email signup form for his ecommerce site (Volusion) using a JQuery and Reveal Modal window.  I tested it on IE10 and it works fine for me, however the opacity doesn't work for him in IE10.  All he sees is a grey background behind the modal window.  The opacity works as expected in other browsers except his version of IE10.

The website is www.minivips.co.uk if anyone is interested in taking a look.

Any suggestions or thoughts would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: No pb for me in IE10. The grey background only appears when switching "Document Mode" to IE8 or IE7. Does your client really have IE10 ?

Comment: It's showing fine for me in IE10. Maybe rather than going for opacity you could create a 2x2 semi transparent png file for the modal background which would work in older IEs too (except 6)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I figured out the problem.  For some reason the client had his website running in compatibility mode.  This caused the opacity not to work.  He was unaware that he was running in compatibility mode, but once I asked him he realized what was going on, and removed it.  Voila, fixed.

Thanks to everyone who took a look at this for me and made suggestions.

James

Answer (score 0):

Looks good for me.

http://www.minivips.co.uk/v/vspfiles/templates/210/css/reveal.css
try to use only one background for .reveal-modal-bg, remove background: rgba(0,0,0,.8);

Comment: Ah ? and why ? since only the last one really matter ?

Comment: Not sure why this would matter. The colour being defined is simply a fallback for browsers that don't have native support for rgba.